# Get NFT Metadata

Tags: onflow-cadence

I'm trying to get the metadata for the Genesis collection from the DriverzNFT contract

this is the script I have

```
import DriverzNFT from 0xa039bd7d55a96c0c
import NonFungibleToken from 0x1d7e57aa55817448
import MetadataViews from 0x1d7e57aa55817448

pub fun main(address: Address): [&DriverzNFT.NFT] {
    let collection = getAccount(address).getCapability(DriverzNFT.CollectionPublicPath)
                        .borrow<&DriverzNFT.Collection{NonFungibleToken.CollectionPublic, NonFungibleToken.Receiver, MetadataViews.ResolverCollection}>(DriverzNFT.CollectionPublic)
                        ?? panic("Can't get collection")

    let returnVals: [&DriverzNFT.NFT] = []

    let ids = collection.getIDs()
    for id in ids {
        returnVals.append(collection.borrowDriverzNFT(id: id))
    }

    return returnVals
}
```

Something is wrong here. I checked the transaction to see where the NFTs are stored and linked when they're sent over, and I checked the contract to see how the collection interface is built. Does anyone have any ideas why I can't pull this data???

The cadence script that I tried is written above. I used the following script to check if the NFT exists in an account:

import NonFungibleToken from 0x1d7e57aa55817448
import MetadataViews from 0x1d7e57aa55817448
import DriverzNFT from 0xa039bd7d55a96c0c

pub fun main(address: Address): Bool {
return getAccount(address)
.getCapability<&DriverzNFT.Collection{NonFungibleToken.CollectionPublic, NonFungibleToken.Receiver, MetadataViews.ResolverCollection}>(DriverzNFT.CollectionPublicPath)
.check()
}

And, this one worked and said that the NFT did exist in my account. But, why then wouldn't the other script share the data? Expecially if I am using the same path in the getCapability object.

Answer (score 1):

Great question. There are a few errors I get when I run your first script:

> 1. error: value of type `DriverzNFT` has no member `CollectionPublic`

This error is because of this part of the script: `DriverzNFT.CollectionPublic`. You can actually delete this part because you already supply a public path in that line. Here is the corrected version:

```
let collection = getAccount(address).getCapability(DriverzNFT.CollectionPublicPath)
                .borrow<&DriverzNFT.Collection{NonFungibleToken.CollectionPublic, NonFungibleToken.Receiver, MetadataViews.ResolverCollection}>() 
                ?? panic("Can't get collection")
```

> 2. error: member of restricted type is not accessible: borrowDriverzNFT

This is coming from this here: `collection.borrowDriverzNFT(id: id)`. The function `borrowDriverzNFT` is only accessible through the `DriverzNFT.CollectionPublic` interface, but you forget to include that type in your capability earlier on!

**Here is a complete corrected version of your script**:

```
import DriverzNFT from 0xa039bd7d55a96c0c 
import NonFungibleToken from 0x1d7e57aa55817448 
import MetadataViews from 0x1d7e57aa55817448

pub fun main(address: Address): [&DriverzNFT.NFT] { 

  let collection = getAccount(address).getCapability(DriverzNFT.CollectionPublicPath)
                .borrow<&DriverzNFT.Collection{DriverzNFT.CollectionPublic, NonFungibleToken.CollectionPublic, NonFungibleToken.Receiver, MetadataViews.ResolverCollection}>() 
                ?? panic("Can't get collection")

  let returnVals: [&DriverzNFT.NFT] = []

  let ids = collection.getIDs()
  for id in ids {
      returnVals.append(collection.borrowDriverzNFT(id: id))
  }

  return returnVals

}
```